# How to process a wav file for WebCRT VAD on Python

Tags: python, webrtc, signal-processing

I'm learning how to use py-webrtcvad library for Python and trying to pick out segments containing speech on a .wav file. Right now, I don't know how to split a .wav files into smaller frames to put it into a vad object. Here's my code below

```
spf = wave.open("test4.wav", "rb")
signal = spf.readframes(-1)

vad = webrtcvad.Vad(3)
sample_rate = 16000
frame_duration = 10  # ms
#TODO: turn signal into segments and run the below print statement in a for loop
print('Contains speech: %s' % (vad.is_speech(signal, sample_rate)))
```

As I have read from https://github.com/wiseman/py-webrtcvad, the frames fed into the vad object must be 16-bit and either 10,20 or 30ms long. My sample is about 9s long and now I don't know how to split it into the appropriate frames. I have tested the example.py in the repo, but it is a bit too complicated for me so I tried to do a very simple example first.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like `frame_generator` from the example could be doing what you're looking for. If not, perhaps you could clarify why it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the frame_generator and achieved the desired result.